# is it bad practise to go back to your last backup when you encounter an unneccessary bug?

Tags: programming-practices, tdd, debugging

I find when I am programming and I fix a bug in one area of the codebase, sometimes something slightly related or maybe unrelated breaks, and as a result I usually copy and paste the fix to a temporary file, restore to the last backup and copy and paste the bug fix and the unrelated bug gets resolved.

My question is, is this a bad programming practise? I don't necessarily care what caused it to break, and most of the time I assume it was some careless typo, but for the rare cases that may be related to faulty software architecture, memory bugs, etc... I feel like I might be being lazy not to go back and find and isolate the cause, especially when it has no practical effect for what seems like a lot of effort just to get validation that it isn't a terminal problem.

Will this bite me in the long run?
Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: Your actual workflow is somewhat unclear. What exactly do you mean by "last backup"? The filesystem-level backup of your development machine? The previous commit in your source code management? If you checked out code to fix a bug, and the resulting code exhibits a new bug that wasn't present before, you need to analyze the cause, not blindly throw stuff away and start from some previous state of the code.

Comment: Don’t you use a versioning system?

Comment: That sounds like a form of "programming by coincidence", which is definitely a bad practice.

Comment: It's not "something breaks" - it's "you broke something and you don't know why". Run `git diff` to see what you changed, and maybe you will see what you broke. Run `git checkout -p` to undo it. And if you aren't using git? Maybe you should be! It's got a learning curve but it's very useful!

Comment: @user253751 Its more if it is worth it to go through and check what that thing that I broke was and why, especially under time constraints, given a lot of the time it is a silly typo and the time required to look back through.

Comment: @jackw11111 well, it doesn't take a lot of time if you use a version control system such as git. It is basically very sophisticated undo. The fact is that you are making changes and *not knowing what you changed*.

Comment: @user253751 I use a diff tool sometimes,but I might see if integrating my workflow with git makes it easier, thanks.

Comment: *"I might see if integrating my workflow with git makes it easier"* - so the answer to @Christoph's question seems to be "no".  Oh dear. You need always 3 mandatory tools for developing software: a text editor, a compiler or interpreter, and a versioning system (in order of importance). A debugger comes directly behind this,

Answer (score 8):

> I don't necessarily care what caused it to break, and most of the time I assume it was some careless typo

You should care; because you can only learn to prevent problems by first identifying them.

This doesn't sound like a technical issue but one of **developer attitude**. If you end up making changes that you never intended to make and are surprised when the compiler (or debug console) tells you so, then the immediate next question is how many unintended changes that did not *break* the compilation have slipped through?

Don't get me wrong, it's normal to make a mistake once in a while and have the compiler/console inform you of something that you weren't aware of. What grates me more about your approach is your seemingly total indifference to actually investigating the issue and instead copy/scorched earth/pasting your work.

> Will this bite me in the long run?

Yes. Both because you're going to eventually create an issue that doesn't get caught before release; and because you're avoiding the necessary learning experience to become a better developer that doesn't make these unintended errors to begin with.

Comment: @user253751: Just because it works does not make it the better option, nor does it mean that you shouldn't try to improve on your development process. The reason I wrote the answer that I did is the underlying indifference in OP's response to errors that they introduced themselves.

Comment: I know this is the right approach, I guess I was unsure whether it was an absolute necessity, given time constraints... ie. You can work more efficiently by restoring a backup whenever something goes wrong instead of trying to reverse a change.

Comment: @jackw11111: If you're hotfixing a business critical bug that needs to be patched ASAP; sure. But those are fringe cases. This answer mostly focuses on the everyday approach rather than specific exceptional cases.

Comment: Using version control, you can always tell what the changes were by diffing against the last version, and you can very easily go back.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you changed something and you don't know what. You *must* know exactly what you changed, or else you don't know that you aren't creating new bugs.

It sounds like you try to fix the bug one way, it doesn't work so you change it back, then you fix it a different way. But when you change it back you accidentally don't change it to how it was originally. So now you've changed it slightly and you don't know how you changed it, and this causes a new bug.

*(sales pitch follows)*

You should really learn to use a *version control system* such as Git - which is currently very popular, but there are other ones too such as Mercurial and (more outdated) Subversion. I use Git, so I'll tell you the Git commands, but other people tell me that Mercurial is easier to learn - your choice.

A version control system keeps track of the changes you have made to your program - right from the beginning, or at least, from when you started using it. It can be like a very sophisticated version of undo. After you change stuff you "commit" your changes - track them in the VCS - and now the VCS can answer questions like "when did I add this line of code?" (`git blame`) and "what things have I changed since the last time I committed?" (`git diff`).

With `git add -p` and/or `git checkout -p` it can show you the changes you made, and let you decide which ones you want to keep. There is no messing around with backups or manual diffs: the program looks through all the files, and tells you "This is something you changed. Do you want to keep it? [y/n]"

You can also undo things you committed: if your boss comes to you and says "hey remember when you fixed this bug, you screwed everything up, undo it right now" the VCS can do that.

Another big feature that all good VCSes have (so, not Subversion) is "branches". You can have a series of commits that's not your "main" one - so you can commit some new feature that's not finished yet, on a branch, and it will keep track of your work on that feature separately. Then if you need to fix a bug in the main version of the program, you can switch to the main branch - and the VCS will undo all your changes related to the feature. You fix the bug, commit (on the main branch), upload the fixed program to the server or whatever. Then you switch back to the unfinished feature branch - and the VCS will redo the changes and you keep working on the feature from the same point you left off. So, you don't have to install something that's not finished, just because you needed to fix a bug.

There can be a steep learning curve (especially for Git), but version control systems are extremely useful. Might as well get started now.

Answer (score 1):

Very blatant answer:

If you consider programming (and, particulary bug fixing) as an exercise in

> if you don't succeed at first, ignore what you did and try something entirely different <sup>1</sup>

your biggest crime is to betray yourself of the opportunity to learn from your own errors.

<sup>1</sup>) This is not a good motto in many trades. I admit its worse with skydivers and brain surgeouns.